# DKImagePickerController fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, arrays

I am trying to integrate `DKImagePickerController` into my project.

The github is here: 
[DKImagePickerController](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/blob/master/DKImagePickerControllerDemo/ViewController.swift)

I did the cocoapods update. The demo project is running fine, but my project has the error when I click button to the view of the photos library:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

in the first line of

```
func showImagePicker() {
        pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets  /* this one
If anyone know what wrong, I appreciate it*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object `pickerController` is only declared, not initialized. The SDK's guide page has already given the example, and I changed some lines for your situation:

```
func showImagePicker() {
    if pickerController == nil {
         pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
    }    

    pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets
    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        self.assets = assets
        //Continue handle images which in the assets.
    }

    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm still unable to fix the problem. It's a little bit complicated since assets is an array of DKassest which is made of NSObject. I real don't know where and how to initiate pickerController = DKImagePickerController(). Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Thank you, Thank you. You are my savior.